# When I don't need an ngCloak directive

Tags: angularjs

Is there any case when I don't need an `ngCloak` directive?

It seems that every tag that somehow uses Angular library needs to define this directive either via `ng-cloak` attribute or `class="ng-cloak"`.

Is there any downside of using this directive for **every** possible element?

Answer (score 0):

ng-cloak will cause your element not to render straight away.  Often elements will look fine without ng-cloak, in which case it would be strange to opt for a blank space.

This will often be the case if you are not using the `{{x}}` syntax.  Perhaps you could use ng-bind instead.

Lots of elements will not be in the DOM at page load.  For example, the template of a directive will obviously not be available until after the digest cycle has already run.  It would be strange to try to cloak something which was not visible in the first place.

Using ng-cloak more than you need to will just hurt performance.